# Send email with Content-Type text/plain

Tags: email

I have problem with emails in Wordpress. I have to send message with Content-Type is text/plain, but in Wordpress default Content-Type is text/html. That change chars like `&` to `&amp;`.

How can I change Content-Type? Please help.

Comment: What did you find when you searched for how to do this? It seems as though a search for example 'wordpress change content-type of email' returns lots of results. If you add the code you have so far to the question it can help people in providing an answer.

Comment: search for example 'wordpress change content-type of email' returns from plain to html, that not resolve my problem. I don't have code. I use Notifications plugin.

Comment: Ah, it depends how that plugin works then. You could try to ask the authors of that plugin for help. If you know how to do it you could try adding the code from my answer to your functions.php, it may do what you want.

Comment: Your code only set header to text/plain, but message is in html. Thanks.

Comment: Then you need to change the message content to plain text... ;-) That happens by whatever writes the message, no automatic conversion can happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't say how you're sending emails, but if you're using `wp_mail`, this is how you change the type to `text/plain`:

```
function wp_set_mail_plaintext() {
    return 'text/plain';
}
add_filter( 'wp_mail_content_type', 'wp_set_mail_plaintext' );
```